# How to fix the Ionic DevApp "white screen of death"?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-devapp

I updated my framework to Ionic 4, and am now having difficulties testing the project on the corresponding Ionic DevApp on my iPhone. (It worked before on my old laptop when I was using Ionic 3. I am currently using a new PC.)

I'll run "ionic serve" and am able to see the name of my project pop up on the app's list. Whenever I open it, however, all I see is the white screen of death. Around thirty seconds later, a notification will pop up saying "Request has timed out."

I've tried working around it by adding the port "localhost: 8100-8600" to my Windows Firewall, but no go.

Please help!

Comment: Hi, are you by chance using Ionic deploy or have the "cordova-plugin-ionic" plugin installed?

Comment: @StephenRomero, yes I am. I've been using "Ionic Serve", but cordova-plugin-ionic is installed with the 6.4.1 version.